# Aligning two separate tabulations

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, columns

I have multiple tabulations one after another, each divided into two columns. I want to have the left column centered about the same first column width, the divider between columns to be at the same horizontal location, and for the last column to be of width 3.5 and left justified.

A crude example would be:

```
                                  Centered Header 1
       The text           Now I have the first description of a longish sentence.
    here Centered         And the second description.
         Text             Finally there is the third.

                                  Centered Header 2
Divided about the same    Remember, this is an example
         Area             So it would be in actual LaTeX typeset... Please see below.
```

Instead, when runninng the following code, I get:

```
...
\vspace{\notationgap}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centerline{\bf Sets and Graphs}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{cp{3.25in}}
$\displaystyle \sA$ & A set\\
$\displaystyle \R$ & The set of real numbers \\
% NOTE: do not use \R^+, because it is ambiguous whether:
% - It includes 0
% - It includes only real numbers, or also infinity.
% We usually do not include infinity, so we may explicitly write
% [0, \infty) to include 0
% (0, \infty) to not include 0
$\displaystyle \{0, 1\}$ & The set containing 0 and 1 \\
$\displaystyle \{0, 1, \dots, n \}$ & The set of all integers between $0$ and $n$\\
$\displaystyle [a, b]$ & The real interval including $a$ and $b$\\
$\displaystyle (a, b]$ & The real interval excluding $a$ but including $b$\\
$\displaystyle \sA \backslash \sB$ & Set subtraction, i.e., the set containing the elements of $\sA$ that are not in $\sB$\\
$\displaystyle \gG$ & A graph\\
$\displaystyle \parents_\gG(\ervx_i)$ & The parents of $\ervx_i$ in $\gG$
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\index{Scalar}
\index{Vector}
\index{Matrix}
\index{Tensor}
\index{Graph}
\index{Set}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{\notationgap}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centerline{\bf Indexing}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{cp{3.25in}}
$\displaystyle \eva_i$ & Element $i$ of vector $\va$, with indexing starting at 1 \\
$\displaystyle \eva_{-i}$ & All elements of vector $\va$ except for element $i$ \\
$\displaystyle \emA_{i,j}$ & Element $i, j$ of matrix $\mA$ \\
$\displaystyle \mA_{i, :}$ & Row $i$ of matrix $\mA$ \\
$\displaystyle \mA_{:, i}$ & Column $i$ of matrix $\mA$ \\
$\displaystyle \etA_{i, j, k}$ & Element $(i, j, k)$ of a 3-D tensor $\tA$\\
$\displaystyle \tA_{:, :, i}$ & 2-D slice of a 3-D tensor\\
$\displaystyle \erva_i$ & Element $i$ of the random vector $\rva$ \\
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{minipage}
```

...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`array`](https://ctan.org/pkg/array) package provides the column type `w{c}{1in}` with fixed width (second argument) and center alignment (first argument). Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{document}
\centerline{\bfseries Sets and Graphs}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{0.7in}p{3.25in}}
$\displaystyle A$ & A set\\
$\displaystyle R$ & The set of real numbers \\
$\displaystyle \{0, 1\}$ & The set containing 0 and 1 \\
$\displaystyle \{0, 1, \dots, n \}$ & The set of all integers between $0$ and $n$\\
$\displaystyle [a, b]$ & The real interval including $a$ and $b$ \\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{1cm}
\centerline{\bfseries Indexing}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{0.7in}p{3.25in}}
$\displaystyle a_i$ & Element $i$ of vector $a$, with indexing starting at 1 \\
$\displaystyle a_{-i}$ & All elements of vector $a$ except for element $i$ \\
$\displaystyle A_{i,j}$ & Element $i, j$ of matrix $A$ \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]